# How to reference a jsp in a different folder

Tags: html, jsp

I just organized the jsp's in my project into separate folders. Now I need to change the src for menu1.jsp

```
<td width="16%" valign="top"><iframe id="ifa"
                                    src="menu1.jsp?page=home" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
                                    scrolling="no" width="190" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                </td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u try foldername/menu1.jsp or can u check hierarchy?

Comment: menu1.jsp is located in the parent folder, so when I use src="new/location/menu1.jsp?page=home" it looks for "new/location/new/menu1.jsp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
 src="menu1.jsp?page=home"
```

to

```
 src="new/location/menu1.jsp?page=home"
```

Comment: menu1.jsp is located in the parent folder, so when I use src="new/location/menu1.jsp?page=home" it looks for "new/location/new/menu1.jsp"

Answer (score 2):

Did you try ../dirname/menu1.jsp as src?